# Magento 2.X: Remove an attribute from product page tabs

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

I have an attribute named warranty. I want to show it on top of the page (it is ok and done), but don't need to show it on the description table on product page with other attributes. what should I do?
want to use something like this: 
  `<?php if($_data['value'] == 'N/A') continue;?>` in attributes.phtml but nut use value, use backend_code or frontend_label. but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Go to **Store->Attributes->Products**
2. Search **warranty** attribute and open it
3. Open tab **Storefront Properties**
4. Select **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** to **Yes**
5. Run Re-index
6. Flush cache

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks, knew it, my problem is: want to show under title, that it shows now, but on more information tab, that shows table of attributes, don't want to show this attribute.

Comment: Did you follow above steps? Because I have already used it in my project and above process removed attribute from information tab.

Comment: Yes, it shows in more information tab yet

Comment: Did you recache your website if its still showing that could be the only possible reason

Comment: Probably information tab is created with some custom module. Enable template hints and check how attributes are getting in that phtml

Comment: Updated question... you know, need some code into attributes.phtml to remove special backend_code